# Storing more than one information into one Node in a singly linked list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to add several information into one Node in a singly linked list... How do I do that?

After asking the user for several vehicle information: `plateNo(String), vehicleType(String), serviceType(String)` I will have to store this information for each vehicle. I have to use a singly linked list to store all the vehicle entering and leaving the wash.

Then, my program should display all the vehicles entering and leaving the vehicle wash with their service order.

How do I do this?

This is my singly LinkedList:

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    private Node<T> head; // first node in the linked list
    private int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Node getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;    // creates an empty linked list
        count = 0;
    }

    public void displayList(){
        Node<T> current = head;     // start at beginning
        while(current != null)      // until end of list,
        {
            System.out.print(current.getData() + " ");
            current = current.getNext();
            //move to next link
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public Node deleteFront()
    {
        Node<T> temp = head;
        if(head.getNext() == null)  // if only one item
            return null;           // return null
        head = head.getNext();      // first --> old next
        count--;
        return temp;
    }

    public void removeValue(T value)
    {
        Node<T> current = head, prev = null;
        while (current != null)
        {   //if current node contains value
            if (value == current.getData())
            {
                //handle front removal (case 1)
                if( prev == null)
                    head = current.getNext();
                else //handle mid removal (case 2)
                    prev.setNext(current.getNext());
                    // prev node now points to                             maxNode's (a.k.a current)                           successor, removing max node.

                break; // remove first occurence only
            }
            // update prev to next position (curr)
            prev = current;
            // move curr to the next node
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }

    public void addFront(T n)
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(n);
        newNode.setNext(head);
        head = newNode;
        count++;
    }
}
```

My Node

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node next;
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(T data) {
       this.data = data;
    }
    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to add several information into one Node in a singly linked list... How do I do that?

... by thinking object-oriented! Create a class that models a vehicle:

```
class Vehicle {
    String plateNo;
    String vehicleType;
    String serviceType;
    // constructors, getters, setters, other methods ...
}
```

You have already a *generic* `Node<T>`, so use it:

```
Vehicle vehicle = callAwesomeMethodThatCreatesVehicleInstance();
Node<Vehicle> node = new Node(vehicle);
```

Now you can use such a node in your linked list.

Comment: Honestly ... this is too broad to answer. I cannot explain OOP concepts in a short and pregnant answer. Please take the time and learn it (might take years).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. You just need to define a new class that contains all the information that you want to store. As you have already made the Node class for a generic data type T, you can then insert the new class that you will make here.

```
class Details{
    String plateNo;
    String vehicleType;
    String serviceType;

    public Details(){
        this.plateNo = "";
        this.vehicleType = "";
        this.serviceType = "";
    }
}
```

Then in your code for the linked list:

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    private Node<Details> head = new Details();
    //rest of the class

}
```

Comment: how do i use this method in main class? sorry i'm new to programming...

Comment: You can create the 'Details' class outside your main class without declaring it private. Then just use 'Details' instead of 'T' in your code - private Node<T> head; becomes private Node<Details> head = new Details();

Comment: Having a `Node<Details>` inside a generic `LinkedList<T>` is a very bad suggestion.

Comment: Why is that a bad idea?

Comment: Well .. it completely undermines the generics mechanism.